# How To Extract Load Balancer Name from Elastic Beanstalk Environment in CloudFormation

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, aws-cloudformation, elastic-load-balancer

I have created a Elastic Beanstalk and CloudWatch Alarm in CloudFormation with the following code snippet:

```
        "ElasticBeanstalkEnvironment": {
        "Type": "AWS::ElasticBeanstalk::Environment",
        "Properties": {
            "ApplicationName": "my-app",
            "EnvironmentName": "my-eb",
            "SolutionStackName": "64bit Amazon Linux 2018.03 v3.0.1 running Tomcat 8 Java 8",
            "OptionSettings": [
                {
                    "Namespace": "aws:elb:loadbalancer",
                    "OptionName": "CrossZone",
                    "Value": "true"
                },
                {
                    "Namespace": "aws:elb:listener:80",
                    "OptionName": "ListenerProtocol",
                    "Value": "HTTP"
                },
                {
                    "Namespace": "aws:elb:listener:80",
                    "OptionName": "InstancePort",
                    "Value": "80"
                },
                etc...
            ]
        },
        "CloudWatchBacken500XXAlarm": {
            "Type": "AWS::CloudWatch::Alarm",
            "Properties" : {
                "AlarmActions": ["arn:aws:sns:us-east-1:12345678:mysnstopic"],
                "Namespace": "AWS/ELB",
                "Dimensions": [{
                    "Name": "LoadBalancerName",
                    "Value" : {
                        "Fn::GetAtt": [
                            "ElasticBeanstalkEnvironment",
                            "EndpointURL"  
                        ]
                    }
                  }],
                "MetricName": "HTTPCode_Backend_5XX",
                "Statistic": "Sum",
                "Period": "60",
                "EvaluationPeriods": "1",
                "ComparisonOperator": "GreaterThanOrEqualToThreshold",
                "Threshold": "1"
                }
        }
```

You can see that the CloudWatch Alarm is configured to alert if the Elastic Beanstalk's load balancer receives 5XX Errors. However I am not able to get the load balancer Name attribute which would look something like this:

```
awseb-e-a-AWSEBLoa-AY8LC6V30OAW
```

Instead the Fn::GetAtt("EndpointURL") attribute returns the load balancer's DNSName which looks something like this:

```
awseb-e-a-AWSEBLoa-AY8LC6V30OAW-175133046.us-east-1.elb.amazonaws.com
```

Which will fail to create the CloudWatch alarm correctly as it expects to get the load balancer Name not DNSName.

What's the best way to get the Load Balancer's Name? I don't want to have to create the Load Balancer as an external resource like "AWS::ElasticLoadBalancing::LoadBalancer" or try to use some substring method to extract the Name string from the DNSName string.

Answer (score 1):

OK I found a solution, its quite the hack, I have been able to extract the LoadBalancerName from the endpoint using several Split/Select/Join calls on the DNSName string returned from - Fn::GetAtt("EndpointURL"). Here is the code:

```
"CloudWatchBackend500XXAlarm": {
"Type": "AWS::CloudWatch::Alarm",
"Properties" : {
    "AlarmDescription": "Elastic Beanstalk Has Received 5XX Backend Connection Errors",
    "AlarmActions": ["arn:aws:sns:us-east-1:1234567890:mysnstopic"],
    "Namespace": "AWS/ELB",
    "Dimensions": [
        {
            "Name": "LoadBalancerName",
            "Value": {
                "Fn::Join": ["", [{
                    "Fn::Select": [
                        "0",
                        {
                            "Fn::Split": ["AWSEBLoa-",
                                {
                                    "Fn::GetAtt": [
                                        "ElasticBeanstalkEnvironment",
                                        "EndpointURL"
                                    ]
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "AWSEBLoa-",
                {
                    "Fn::Select": [
                        "0",
                        {
                            "Fn::Split": ["-",
                                {
                                    "Fn::Select": [
                                        "1",
                                        {
                                            "Fn::Split": ["AWSEBLoa-",
                                                {
                                                    "Fn::GetAtt": [
                                                        "ElasticBeanstalkEnvironment",
                                                        "EndpointURL"
                                                    ]
                                                }
                                            ]
                                        }
                                    ]
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]]
        }
        }
    ],                  
    "MetricName": "HTTPCode_Backend_5XX",
    "Statistic": "Sum",
    "Period": "60",
    "EvaluationPeriods": "1",
    "ComparisonOperator": "GreaterThanOrEqualToThreshold",
    "Threshold": "1"
}
```

}

ie the code above is able to extract 'awseb-k-3-AWSEBLoa-11B26NY4PQB9A' from 'awseb-k-3-AWSEBLoa-11B26NY4PQB9A-739614614.us-east-1.elb.amazonaws.com' and the CloudWatch alarm works perfectly. I think I would have to adjust the code to work with internal load balancers, ie formatted with 'internal-' at the start of the DNSName but I am fine for now.

I've submitted a request to AWS asking them to add a CloudFormation method to return the LoadBalancer Name and not just the DNSName.

Answer (score 1):

Using ebextensions would be much easier to create an alarm - as fetching the ELB name is as easy as Value: { "Ref" : "AWSEBLoadBalancer" }

Create a file with .config extension (say - BackendErrors.config) and place it in a folder with name ".ebextensions". Complete ebextension will be as follows:

```
Resources:
  CloudWatchBacken500XXAlarm:
    Type: AWS::CloudWatch::Alarm
    Properties:
      AlarmDescription: "Elastic Beanstalk Has Received 5XX Backend Connection Errors"
      AlarmName: { "Fn::Join" : ["", [{ "Ref" : "AWSEBEnvironmentName" }, "-Backend-5XX-Alarm." ]]}
      AlarmActions:
        - "arn:aws:sns:us-east-1:123456789012:mysnstopic"
      Namespace: AWS/ELB
      Dimensions:
        - Name: LoadBalancerName
          Value: { "Ref" : "AWSEBLoadBalancer" }
      MetricName: HTTPCode_Backend_5XX
      Statistic: Sum
      Period: 60
      EvaluationPeriods: 1
      Threshold: 1
      ComparisonOperator: GreaterThanOrEqualToThreshold
```

The .ebextensions folder should be created at the top level of your application source bundle:

```
~/workspace/my-application/
|-- .ebextensions
|   |-- BackendErrors.config
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to the environment name, you can perform a [`DescribeEnvironmentResources`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/elasticbeanstalk/describe-environment-resources.html) API call. The response would include information about the loadbalancer of your environment.

Comment: how can he integrate that api call into cloudformation?

Answer (score 0):

in case it is not obvious what the code above does:
it extracts the name part before -xxxxxxxx.region.elb.amazonaws.com

This is sufficient for classic loadbalancers because they do only have a name and Cloudwatch is able to monitor these LBs by their name.

For application loadbalancers it is a different story:
ApplicationLoadbalancers besides their name, they do have an `arn` on their own in the format:

`arn:aws:elasticloadbalancing:REGION:ACCOUNT:loadbalancer/XXXXX/my-load-balancer/DDDDDDDD`

Where **XXXXX** is a region dependent string ( I found *application* in us and *app* in europe) and **DDDDDDDD** is an arbitrary number.

Cloudwatch needs this `loadBalancerFullName` to monitor this LB.
So sadly you can't use this trick if you have an application loadbalancer.

Answer (score -1):

Coming here a few years later, it looks like Amazon have added the attribute now :

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-elasticloadbalancingv2-loadbalancer.html

To quote:

> LoadBalancerFullName
>
> The full name of the load balancer. For example, app/my-load-balancer/50dc6c495c0c9188.

So you can now do :

```
  Dimensions:
    - Name: LoadBalancer
      Value: !GetAtt YourALBRef.LoadBalancerFullName
```

Comment: The question is how to extract the load balancer ARN created by Elastic Beanstalk.